# android: append audio

Tags: android, audio

I have multiple files that I play in my android code using mediaplayer.I want them to play one after another.

Is there a way to append audio that i play using MediaPlayer(or similar)? or Is there a way to execute a code at end of playing a media file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html):

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //you can play the another audio file here
    }
});
```